# How to refactor repeated code for creating Intents?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I primarily work with a different programming language but am now starting to get into android development, it's been many years since I last did any java programming so I'm way behind on terminology.
In an app that I'm working on these is a code block that looks something like this inside a class called `NotificationService`

```
Intent intent;
if (type == "1") {
  intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, ActivityOne.class);
} else if (type == "6") {
  intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, ActivityTwo.class);
} else {
  intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this, ActivityThree.class);
}
```

The same code block is more or less repeated in an activity

```
Intent intent;
if (type == "1") {
  intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);
} else if (type == "6") {
  intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
} else {
  intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ActivityThree.class);
}
```

As new `type`'s are added I will need to maintain two lists of if/elseif/else statements, how would I go about refactoring this so that I can reuse the same logic in the two different places (one being the NotificationSerivce and the second being the ListActivity?

Comment: Don't compare strings by == operator, use `"1".equals(type)` or consider introduction of a type enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about declaring a method for getting activity's from type.

```
Class<?> getActivityFromType(int type) {
    if(type == 1) return ActivityOne.class;
    if(type == 2) return ActivityTwo.class;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return null
}
```

This way you don't need to write else's and you can create a new intent like following:

```
intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, getActivityFromType(1));
```

And the code is much more cleaner. In addition you can put all these intent creating logic and codes inside a factory class, so that no other classes need to know about these logics of creating intent. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array with all the intents you need:

```java
Intent[] intents = {new Intent(), new Intent(), ...};

intent = intents[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could switch to Kotlin, sealed classes could help you a lot. Here an example.

Let's say you have different types. For example, type 1 and type 2. For now, let's think just about these two types. We can use a sealed class, like this:

```
sealed class MyType {
    class Type1 : MyType()
    class Type2 : MyType()
}
```

Now, we can define our pairs of type<->activity, like this:

```
sealed class MyPair(type: MyType, activity: Activity) {

    data class Pair1(val type: MyType.Type1, val activity: Activity1) : MyPair(type, activity)
    data class Pair2(val type: MyType.Type2, val activity: Activity2) : MyPair(type, activity)
}
```

We are pairing a MyType with an Activity. If we have to add an other Type, everything we need to do is adding it in the MyType sealed class. If we need to map that new type with a particular Activity, we will add the pairing in the MyPair sealed class.

To retrieve the type, we can now use this:

```
fun getType(type: MyType) : KType? {
    MyPair::class.nestedClasses
        .map { it.memberProperties }
        .filter { it.filter { it.returnType in MyType::class.nestedClasses
            .map { it.createType()}}[0].returnType == type::class.createType() }
        .map {it.filter { it.name == "activity" }}
        .firstOrNull().let {
            it?.first()?.let { return it.returnType }
        }

    return DefaultActivity::class.createType()
}
```

Of course, you'll have to change the DefaultActivity, but the code in the getType method won't change and you will have the DefaultActivity if you just add a type, the mapped Activity if you add a map for that new type.

Last: you'll have to change your "type" variable's type, from Int to MyType.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but kotlin isn't an option at this stage